# Problem with basic regex to match ending optional character

Tags: regex

Hi all i was hoping someone could help be with some basic regex i am really struggling with.

Bascially i need to match a url for redirection. I have been using

```
^~/abc(/)?
```

however i need to change the end part to just check the last optional character as this will also match `^/abcd`

Answer (score 3):

How about `^~/abc(/?)`

or more generally: `^~/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PCRE, you will want:

```
^~/abc(.)?$
```

Which will match "~/abc" followed (optionally) by any single character, which will be captured. Leave the () off if you don't need to capture said character.

Just like `^` matches the beginning of string (or line, depending upon mode), `$` matches the end of string (or line).

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this :
^~/([a-zA-Z0-9]+/?)*$